# What to do when making interface where some implementations don't use a variable?

Tags: java, oop

Say you have an interface `Employee` with the method signature `int calculateWage(int hoursPerWeek, int overtime);`. What if one implementation per week doesn't use the variable `overtime`? For example the code

```
int calculateWage(int hoursPerWeek, int overtime) {
  return hoursPerWeek*wage;
}
```

looks silly and produces warnings as overtime isn't used.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Your interface might be too narrow and/or the implementation doesn't really fit into it (e.g. what you have here is `EmployeeThatDoesNotHaveOvertime implements EmployeeThatWorksOvertime`). Redefine some stuff, or calculate the wage using overtime and assume an object that doesn't get overtime will always pass in 0.

Comment: I think the correct answer to this question is "The employee gets screwed".

Comment: Who is giving you warnings, by the way?  `javac` doesn't say anything at all when I try it.

Comment: Eclipse isn't giving me any warnings either.

Comment: @ajb, it will be the employee, then ;)

Comment: @ajb Netbeans, maybe you're doing something wrong. If `func(int x)` never uses `x` in it's body it will produce a warning. Same way as `calculateWage()` never uses `overTime`.

Comment: Well, the employee shouldn't be warning the programmer, it should be warning the National Labor Relations Board or something.

Comment: @Celeritas I don't use Netbeans, so why are you sure I'm doing something wrong?  It's pretty normal for parameters to be unused, and doesn't always indicate a mistake; so not all compilers/IDEs give warnings about this.  (OK, I see you edited this to "maybe".  But no, I'm not doing anything wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem.  Interfaces are used because they can, in theory, represent any number of different classes that implement those methods.  It's entirely sensible that some of those classes (even if they exist only in theory) might use all of the parameters, and others might not.

In fact, I think it's a very normal occurrence for some of the interfaces defined by the language.  In many, if not most, of the classes I've written that implement [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), I don't use the parameter to `ActionPerformed` at all, because the particular implementation doesn't need it.  But the information is there for a case where it *is* needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the interface assumes that hours-per-week *includes* the overtime hours, all implementations *not* treating overtime quantities with *higher* wage still should compute

```
 return (hoursPerWeek - overtime)*wage + overtime*wage;
```

with a comment that overtime isn't paid extra.

If the interface does not assume that hours-per-week include the overtime hours, the implmentation should either

```
 return hoursPerWeek*wage + overtime*0;  // why did they work overtime?
```

or

```
if( overtime > 0 ) throw new IllegalArgumentException( "..." ); // unexpected!
return hoursPerWeek*wage;
```

This will, in any case, uphold the contract made by the interface using defensive coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface (class?) really looks silly and suspicious for analyser. Obvious answer is to introduce 2 methods: 1 which doesn't have `overtime` parameter and one that has. Something like this:

```
int calculateWage(int hoursPerWeek, int overtime) {
    return (hoursPerWeek + overtim) * wage;
}

int calculateWage(int hoursPerWeek) {
    return calculateWage(hoursPerWeek, 0);
}
```

If you care about classes which will need to implement both methods - OK, in Java 8 you can base on `default` implementation and in practice good analyzer should distinguish this from other way you can follow:

```
interface WageCalculator {

    int calculateWage(int hoursPerWeek, int overtime);

}

class GreedyWageCalculator implements WageCalculator {

    @Override
    int calculateWage(int hoursPerWeek, int overtime) {
        return hoursPerWeek * wage;
    }

}
```

This approach is illustrated [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/9417670).

And worst case you can rely on old dump `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` despite I personally dislike this approach. Another way is to use some 'empty' code fragment. There is couple of widely used one but again, I dislike this `make your compiler happy` practice. Question is slightly unclear: if we speak about interfaces, why implementation is here? If we speak about interfaces with default implementation you can always implement 2 methods like in my first example above.

Comment: but is that allowed to have an overloaded calculateWage like that? Now each implementing class needs to define both methods so I don't think that works?

Comment: @Celeritas It's definitely allowed, and yes, each implementing class needs to define both methods.

Comment: I think this answer missing the point of an `interface`.  An API, whether it's for a concrete class, abstract class, or interface, should provide two methods like this if it's reasonable to expect that the **caller** would find it convenient to have both methods available.  But I think you're basing this based not on the needs of the callers, but rather on the different **implementations** you envision.  And that should _not_ be the basis of deciding what the API looks like.